# Robotium way to type text in EditText

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, robotium

```
solo.enterText("something")
```

method includes two actions:

1. enter text in EditView
2. click OK button in softkeyboard

**I need method only for typing text.** After typing text, the keyboard must be still opened and cursor is on EditText. Then I click on OK Button in softkeybord using solo.sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);

```
solo.typeText(0,"Something")
```

doesn't work.

I am using Robotium 5.2.1